# Display HTML if two conditions are true or another two are true or third part of conditions are true

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have php if statement that should display certain HTML code if two conditions are true or another two are true or third part of conditions are true.

I have several arrays - `$Options_arr`, `$MoreOptions_arr`, `$Special_arr` .

To explain in the easiest possible way I want to do this:

`if(!empty($Options_arr[0]) && $Options_arr[0]!="")` or

`(!empty($MoreOptions_arr[0]) &&  $MoreOptions_arr[0]!="")` or

`(!empty($Special_arr[0]) &&  $Special_arr[0]!="")`

{?> some HTML here

All help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: No need for `!=""`, `empty()` checks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BragG, you can use `elseif`

Like:

```
if((!empty($Options_arr[0]) && $Options_arr[0]!="") || 
   (!empty($MoreOptions_arr[0]) &&  $MoreOptions_arr[0]!="") || 
   (!empty($Special_arr[0]) &&  $Special_arr[0]!=""))
{
 //  some html or any code
}
```

I hope that is what you were looking for..

Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` already checks for empty string `""` so it's shorter:

```
if(!empty($Options_arr[0]) || !empty($MoreOptions_arr[0]) || !empty($Special_arr[0])) {
    //some HTML here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing some brackets. Also || is more frequently used than OR

```
if((!empty($Options_arr[0]) && $Options_arr[0]!="") || (!empty($MoreOptions_arr[0]) &&  $MoreOptions_arr[0]!="") || (!empty($Special_arr[0]) &&  $Special_arr[0]!="")){
    echo '<p>hello</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically already there...

```
if (
      (!empty($Options_arr[0]) && $Options_arr[0]!="") 
   || (!empty($MoreOptions_arr[0]) && $MoreOptions_arr[0]!="")
   || (!empty($Special_arr[0]) && $Special_arr[0]!="")

){
```

...do something

Basically you write an `if` statement that resolves if any of the sub-statements are true by joining the sub-statements together with `OR`s